# GraphQL ignores some (but not all) arbitrarily assigned markdown frontmatter data

Tags: graphql, gatsby

First time trying out Gatsby and it's been a pleasure. However I ran into a strange GraphQL problem:

I'm using the gatsby-source-filesystem and gatsby-transformer-remark plugins to pull in content from markdown files.

The frontmatter data is not the same across all of them (except for `title`). Some have a `date` string (the blog posts), same have a `tag` array, some have a `gallery` object.

Now the problem is that some of this arbitrarily assigned frontmatter data is available in GraphQL and some is not. For example if I try to query the date I always get the "GraphQL Error Unknown field `date` on type `frontmatter_2`". Whereas if I query the tags, I get the tag array for those items that contain one and `tags: null` for those who don't.

What's the problem here? How can I always get `null` as value of a field that doesn't exist in a node?

It's probably of note that this behaviour changes depending on the directory structure of my markdown files. If I move them around, some frontmatter fields become available in GraphQL that previously weren't and vice versa. It also happens that after some code changes get pushed via HMR, some fields become available - but after I restart Gatsby, they're gone again despite not having touched the code in-between.

Thanks a lot for helping!

**Edit**:

After unsuccessfully banging my head against this for some time, I resorted to ensuring that all markdown frontmatter has the same fields of the same type.

I guess the

> TODO link to docs on auto-inferring types/fields.

part of the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/) is about this problem.

When I have more time, I'd like to learn more about GraphQL and how it works in Gatsby. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but check out GraphiQL with Gatsby, it's a huge help in understanding what data is available when. http://localhost:8000/___graphql

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know about GraphiQL and it is indeed very helpful. However, my problem is about how gatsby-transformer-remark parses the frontmatter and decides which data ends up how in the Node Interface. – There have been many updates to it since I asked the question. Maybe it has been fixed… I gotta try again soon.

Comment: Gatsby "infers" the GraphQL schema from the data available. [This](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3913) issue suggests that some fields, if not present in every record, might occasionally get dropped. Your workaround of ensuring every field is on every document is probably the most robust solution, at least for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be hitting [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3913) bug where sometimes sparsely populated fields seem to be missed from GraphQL.

However, to answer your specific question, how can you ensure that you always get `null` for empty fields. You could do that by using the `onCreateNode` hook. This hook gets called for every node.

Something like the following pseudocode will achieve your goal:

```js
exports.onCreateNode = ({node, getNode, boundActionCreators}) => {
  const { createNodeField } = boundActionCreators

  if (_.get(node, 'internal.type') === `MarkdownRemark`) {

    // Repeat this for each field
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'date',
      value: _.get(node, 'frontmatter.date', 'default date'),
    })

  }
}
```

This will copy values from `frontmatter` to `fields` and ensure that they are always present with some default value if they don't already exist. You can add tests on `node.internal.type` to filter for specific node types

NOTE: This is totally untested, off the cuff, pseudocode, use at own risk!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll test this soon and mark it as the answer if it works. Thanks again!